# Canvas createImageData, predicting "out of memory"

Tags: javascript, memory, canvas, out-of-memory

Looks like browsers have a memory limit to ImageData objects (or it's just takes all available to JS memory, I don't know), and when you reach it, browsers handle it differently.

Firefox just throws DOMException

`DOMException [IndexSizeError: "Index or size is negative or greater than the allowed amount"
code: 1
nsresult: 0x80530001
out of memory`

But Webkit-based browsers (Chrome/Opera) just freezes the tab, and then crashed. I need to know, how to predict "out of memory" error, and prevent browser tab from crashing.

Here's a living example of how it will be used: http://akira.selfip.org/pj/?input=http://www.pixeljoint.com/files/icons/full/rewind_tape.gif Page will automatically try to load image, that causes out of memory error. It happens because of creating separated ImageData object for every frame of Gif file.

Comment: there isn't really a way to predict it other than writing an extension to interface with the OS and check in predicted memory needs vs. available memory. The general best practice is to not use huge canvas elements, as they take up a tremendous amount of space. A not unusual 2000x2000 image, for instance needs at least 4*2000*2000 = 16mb for its UInt8Array data backing, and that's before you start duplicating the pixel array(s) during blitting operations, and on a single frame if you're using canvas for multi-frame animation. Canvas gets *very* expensive, very fast.

Comment: Okay, is there any way to avoid out of memory, like placing frames as Image objects with Base64 data?

Comment: if you need to do heavy image work, you can always send the image to the server, do the processing there, then send the result back. Alternatively, use a small canvas and draw tiles, then process those separately (so a 250x250px canvas, for instance, with `ctx.drawImage(img,0,0)`, processing, `ctx.drawImage(img,-250,0)`, processing, etc, but then you're likely going to hit the memory limit once you aggregate the tiles again. Without code, there's much else to say in terms of what you specifically can do to mitigate the problem